# ListView does not show first column

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, listviewitem

I have the method here below. Before this method, I was getting the data from one table and now from two tables so I changed ListView as shown below.

Before using two different tables the ListView was designed at properties tab and all was working good.

The method below when writing items bypass the first column and begins from the second.

What is the bug ?

Any help will be very precious.

```
    private void ShowPage()
    {
        // some declarations such count,LineNbr etc...
        if (PublicVariables.PrintData == 1)
        {
            // seeting column headers and with and alignement if PrintData=1
            newtmp = new string[5];
        }
        else
        {
            // seeting column headers and with and alignement if PrintData=2
            newtmp = new string[7];
        }
        LineNbr = File.ReadAllLines(fName).Length;
        ppc.View = View.Details;
        ListViewItem DispItem = new ListViewItem();
        while (counter < LineNbr && (line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] tmp = line.Split('|');            // Splitting the Data
            sayac = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (tmp[i] != "")
                {
                    newtmp[sayac] = tmp[i];
                    ++sayac;
                }
            }
            for (int a=0; a<newtmp.Length; ++a)       // I add to SubItems
                DispItem.SubItems.Add(newtmp[a]);     
            ppc.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {DispItem}); // I pass to ListView ppc
            if (PublicVariables.PrintData == 1)            //Initialise newtmp string
                newtmp = new string[5]; 
            else
                newtmp = new string[7];
            DispItem = new ListViewItem();               // Initialiase ListViewItem
            ++counter;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      for (int a=0; a<newtmp.Length; ++a)       // I add to SubItems
            DispItem.SubItems.Add(newtmp[a]);     
        ppc.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {DispItem}); // I pass to Lis
```

Instead of those lines above, I have to do as below :(

```
            DispItem = new ListViewItem(newtmp);
            ppc.Items.Add(DispItem);
```

I was trying everything to resolve this.

After all, my excuses for those who give mind

Comment: I was thinking over the same thing :), was just googling for the AddRange method, wasn't sure what it does.

Comment: @theMayer Yes I found the solution and the mistake I've done. That was destroying me since 2 days